# Upgrade EMR Cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, amazon-emr

I have a small, long-running cluster provisioned on EMR with Spark, Zeppelin, Hue, etc.... I have configured Hue users, I have several notebooks in Zeppelin that I'm using... all is working well. However, I'm running emr-4.3.0 and I want to upgrade to the emr-4.5.0 image. I don't want to re-create the cluster since I would need to reconfigure all the applications again and figure out how to transfer user data over (saved notebooks, saved queries in Hue, etc.).

How can I upgrade an already-running cluster to the latest EMR image?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no EMR API's to upgrade EMR AMI's. You will need to migrate to a newer AMI manually. If you are concerned about constant updates. Some suggestions are-

1. Hue user information and query histories -> You might use a centralized hue DB for storing users / query history on an external database instead of local mysql : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/hue-rds.html
2. Zeppelin -> Use the persistent S3 storage for storing notebooks

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty late. But EMR now allows you to modify cluster config on the fly. (From EMR version 5.21)

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/modifying-your-cluster-on-the-fly-with-amazon-emr-reconfiguration/